# Not able to decrypt(AES) in iOS(Swift) from Java

Tags: java, ios, swift, encryption, aes

I am unable to decrypt data on iOS(Swift) which I am getting from the Java server. But if I encrypt a data on iOS and then decrypt, it works well. There might be some variance on both side's AES code which I am not able to identify. Please help me.

Similar question asked here: https://github.com/krzyzanowskim/CryptoSwift/issues/458

iOS Decryptor

```
            let password = "SOME_ENCRYPTION_KEY"
            let iv = AES256Crypter.randomIv()
            let key = try AES256Crypter.createKey(password: password.data(using: .utf8)!, salt: salt)
            let aes = try AES256Crypter(key: key, iv: iv)
            let encryptedData = "encrypted_data".data(using: .utf8)
            let decryptedData = try aes.decrypt(encryptedData!)
            let decryptedString =  String(decoding: decryptedData, as: UTF8.self)
            print("Decrypted  string: \(decryptedString)")
```

Java Encryptor

```
SecretKeySpec secretKey;
        try {
            byte[] key = ENCRYPTION_KEY.getBytes("UTF-8");
            MessageDigest sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
            key = sha.digest(key);
            key = Arrays.copyOf(key, 16);
            secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key, "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("\nException while encrypting " + strToEncrypt + " \nerror: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```

Comment: I could have decrypt the data encrypted by your Java code using Apple's standard CommonCrypto. Your may need to modify your code to match the encryption method in Java, though I cannot point out where to modify... I have never seen `AES256Crypter`.

Comment: Although I'm not familiar with IOS or AES256Crypter, it does appear that very little on the Java side matches the IOS side. The Java key size is 16, which makes it AES-128. No mode or padding is specified on the Java side, which leads to provider-specific defaults being chosen and is inherently non-portable.

Comment: Beware of system defaults which can differ across different systems.  Make sure you specify *everything* explicitly on both systems so they match: mode, IV/nonce, key, padding, KDF etc. You may even need to set the character mode: UTF-8, UTF-16 etc.  Any difference will cause problems as crypto is designed to fail if there is even a small mismatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the code for **Encryption in Java** 
and **Decryption for iOS(Swift and Android(Kotlin)**. This works well but I am still open for a better solution.

Java Code

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

public class EncryptionUtils {

    private static String ENCRYPTION_KEY = "1234512345123456";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String encyString = new EncryptionUtils().encrypted("HJUSER153");
        System.out.println("Encrypted String:" + encyString);
     }

    public String encrypted(String strToEncrypt) {
         try {
            IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(ENCRYPTION_KEY.getBytes());

            SecretKeySpec keyspec = new SecretKeySpec(ENCRYPTION_KEY.getBytes(), "AES");

            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec);
            return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(strToEncrypt.getBytes("UTF-8")));
            //encrypted = cipher.doFinal(text.getBytes());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("\nException while encrypting " + strToEncrypt + " \nerror: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

iOS Swift Code

Add this in pod file - 
**pod 'CryptoSwift'**

```
import CryptoSwift

func decrypt(input:String)->String?{
        let key = "1234512345123456"
        do{
            let d=Data(base64Encoded: input)
            let decrypted = try AES(key: key, iv: key, padding: .pkcs5).decrypt(
                d!.bytes)
            return String(data: Data(decrypted), encoding: .utf8)
        }catch{

        }
        return nil
    }
```

Android

```
import android.util.Base64
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException
import javax.crypto.Cipher
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec

class CypherHelper {

    private var ivspec: IvParameterSpec? = null
    private var keyspec: SecretKeySpec? = null
    private var cipher: Cipher? = null
    private val ENCRYPTION_KEY: String = "1234567890123456"

    init {
        ivspec = IvParameterSpec(ENCRYPTION_KEY.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8))
        keyspec = SecretKeySpec(ENCRYPTION_KEY.toByteArray(), "AES")
        try {
            cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
        } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: NoSuchPaddingException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    fun decrypt(valueToDecrypt: String): String {
        var decryptValue: String = ""
        val enc = CypherHelper()
        if (valueToDecrypt.isEmpty())
            decryptValue = String(enc.decryptInternal(valueToDecrypt)!!)

        return decryptValue
    }

    private fun decryptInternal(code: String?): ByteArray? {
        if (code == null || code.isEmpty()) {
            throw Exception("Empty string")
        }

        var decrypted: ByteArray? = null
        try {
            cipher?.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keyspec, ivspec)
            decrypted = cipher?.doFinal(Base64.decode(code, Base64.DEFAULT))
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            throw Exception("[decrypt] " + e.message)
        }
        return decrypted
    }
}
```